# I declared a character variable but I am being told that my chosen symbol cannot have a type, I have tried other symbols, but get the same error

Tags: fortran, debug-symbols

for some reason my compiler keeps telling me that my chosen symbol, 'plate' cannot have a type, I have tried others but I still get the same issue, this is my code:

```
implicit none
character (len=9):: make
character (len=8):: color,plate
character (len=10):: date 
integer:: hr, mn, sc, i
open (1,file='logfile.txt')

read(1,*) ! read nothing
read(1,*) ! read nothing
do i=1,5
    read(1,100) make, color, plate, date, hr, mn, sc
end do
100 format (1x,a9,1x,a8,1x,a8,1x,a10,1x,i2,1x,i2,1x,i2)

close (1)
end program plate
```

This is the error I recieve

```
39 | Character (len=8):: plate
   |                         1
Error: Symbol 'plate' at (1) cannot have a type

51 |     read(1,100) make, color, plate, date, hr, mn, sc
   |                                   1
Error: 'plate' at (1) is not a variable
```

What I want to do is read a text file, and list the information read in another file based on a certain set of conditions (which I have yet to define). currently I am just in the process of making sure everything is read properly.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `plate` is the name of your program. Therefore you cannot have a variable that is also named `plate`. These namespaces are not distinct, each entity must be named differently.

The name of the program is global identifier (F2018 19.2). The name of the variable is a local identifier of class 1 (F2018 19.3).

F2018 19.3.2.1 says

> Within its scope, a local identifier of an entity of class (1) or
> class (4) shall not be the same as a global identifier used in that
> scope unless...

The unless points do not apply here.

Comment: We need to note that the `end program plate` isn't actually a valid way to end the example of the question.

Comment: I assumed that the code sample might be clipped. `program plate` is indeed necessary at the start of the program.

Comment: I changed the name of my program and the issue is now resolved, thank you!

Comment: It's worth adding here that Fortran is not case-sensitive, so changing `plate` to `Plate` in one place would give the same error.

Comment: Can anybody link where in the Fortran standard is program and variable name collision forbidden? It surprised me as function and variable name collision is not a problem.

Comment: @Jorge F2018 19.2
 Global identifiers and  19.3 Local identifiers and point 19.3.1.2